# Polymorphic Relations for inheritance

Tags: laravel-5.6, relationships

in my database, I have an inheritance situation.
there is a table called **Products** that holds the common attributes among all the categories like **Suits**, **Footwears** and **Fabric Packs**, each product should be only one of the mentioned categories.
i've used the method `$table->morphs('taggable');` to create the appropriate columns.

and implemented polymorphic relationships of eloquent like this:

```
    class Product extends Model
{
    public function taggable()
     {
         return $this->morphTo();
     }

}
```

```
class Footwear extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('Product', 'taggable');
    }
}
```

th same thing in the other two classes.
but when i use tinker to verify the relationship it seems to work from one side !

```
>>> App\Model\Product::find(65)->taggable
[!] Aliasing 'FabricPack' to 'App\Model\FabricPack' for this Tinker session.
=> App\Model\FabricPack {#2928
     id: 5,
     length: 0.7,
     created_at: "2018-07-30 12:19:51",
     updated_at: "2018-07-30 12:19:51",
   }
```

i think `App\Model\FabricPack::find(5)->tag` should return the appropriate product but instead returns null.

```
>>> App\Model\FabricPack::find(5)
=> App\Model\FabricPack {#2929
     id: 5,
     length: 0.7,
     created_at: "2018-07-30 12:19:51",
     updated_at: "2018-07-30 12:19:51",
   }
>>> App\Model\FabricPack::find(5)->tag
=> null
```

so, any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**taggable_type** values should like this `App\Model\{subclass}`.